# Why is my swap used even if my physical RAM isn't full?

Tags: ubuntu, memory, virtual-memory

Sometimes I have observed in Ubuntu's System Manager that without the physical RAM being used completely, the swap memory starts getting used.

Why is it so?

Comment: There is a parameter called swappiness https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwapFaq#What_is_swappiness_and_how_do_I_change_it.3F which can be tweaked. A lightly loaded desktop with a GB of RAM can be set at 10 (out of 100).

Comment: Check out this thread: [askubuntu.com][1]


  [1]: http://askubuntu.com/questions/157793/why-is-swap-being-used-even-though-i-have-plenty-of-free-ram

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the Ubuntu Wiki [Swap Faq](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwapFaq)

> A significant number of the pages used by these large programs *during
>   its startup may only be used for initialization and then never used
>   again.* The system can swap out those pages and free the memory for
>   other programs or even for the disk cache. In these cases, swap will
>   be used to help the system handle any extra load.

I feel that the linux kernel does this optimally, and quite well, so you need not worry at all. You could reduce swappiness to increase your RAM usage, but I would not recommend that.

Answer (score 1):

The OS sends pages to swap `just in case`. It does this so that *if* swap is needed it can remove the *"swapped"* pages from memory without the delay of writing them to disk.

I have no proof of this, but I would assume it does this when it has some spare time, so it can do it without impacting normal operations.